# dotnet watch - no frameworks found

Tags: .net, linux, f#, command-line-interface

coming back to .NET after a little more than a decade for F# and I'm having trouble running a very basic hello world app with `dotnet watch`.

Basically `dotnet run` starts the app as expected but `dotnet watch` fails with "no frameworks were found". Even `dotnet watch --help` fails with this error.

I'm on linux and have .net6.0 and .net7.0 installed.

EDIT1: output of `dotnet --info`

```bash
.NET SDK:
 Version:   7.0.100
 Commit:    e12b7af219

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     endeavouros
 OS Version:  
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         arch-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.100/

Host:
  Version:      7.0.0
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       d099f075e4

.NET SDKs installed:
  6.0.111 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
  7.0.100 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.11 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.0 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Other architectures found:
  None

Environment variables:
  DOTNET_ROOT       [/usr/share/dotnet]

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
```

Comment: The command is available for me on linux. Seems a bit like your .NET installation is somehow incomplete. What's the output of `dotnet --info`?

Comment: @PMF updated the question, thanks for taking the time and sorry about my late answer, in a hospital rn

Comment: Thanks for the update. Unfortunately, I cannot see anything out of the ordinary (except that 6.0.111 is not the latest 6.0 SDK). I don't know where the missing modules should be. `dotnet tool list -g` doesn't list the watch command, even if it is working.

Comment: I would try to reinstall the SDKs.

Comment: @PMF it seems `watch` is part of the aspnet runtime which has to be explicitly installed, see answer below

Answer (score 2):

solution found in [recent github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/29223): install `aspnet-runtime`.

`dotnet --list-runtimes` should include "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" which is mentioned in the original error message.